# Having a problem removing TextViews from a LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, refresh, textview, android-linearlayout

I am programmatically adding TextViews to a LinearLayout, and deleting them on touch. It all works fine except when the last TextView is touched it doesn't get removed. If I do anything else on the screen like get rid of the keyboard or scroll down at all, the last TextView will be deleted, which makes me think it's a refresh problem, but I have no idea how to solve that.

Here's some of the code I'm using:

```
final TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("Test");

tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        linearlayout1.removeView(tv1);

    }
});
```

I have also added this code in to try to solve the problem but it didn't change anything:

```
if (linearlayout1.getChildCount() == 1) {
    linearlayout1.removeAllViewsInLayout();
}
```

Comment: This sounds more of a bug, but one thing you could try is hiding your TextView before removal `tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Or alternatively you could add `linearlayout1.invalidate()` after removal of the last item to trigger redrawing.

Comment: I'm going to give these a go now. Thanks.

Comment: invalidate works :) Thanks :) If you leave this comment as an answer I can tick it for others to find

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This sounds more of a bug in Android, but one thing you could try is hiding your `TextView` before removal:

```
tv1.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Or alternatively you could add:

```
linearlayout1.invalidate()
```

after removal of the last item to trigger redrawing.