# removing TextView from LinearLayout after checkbox clicked

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Having a problem removing TextViews from a LinearLayout programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934642/having-a-problem-removing-textviews-from-a-linearlayout-programmatically)

Hi I am still pretty new to this Android stuff and I was wondering if anyone could figure out how to solve my problem? i checked all over google for tips on how to remove a textView from a LinearLayout but none of the cases worked.

```
if (breakCheck.isChecked()) {
            if (!clickedOnce) {
                ll.addView(prompt_break);
                prompt_break.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                clickedOnce = true;
            }
        } else {
            prompt_break.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ll.removeView(prompt_break);
                ll.invalidate;

        }
}
```

I am trying to make a TextView appear when the checkBox is checked and then delete it everytime that the box is unchecked, but nothing I do can remove the TextView after im done :( please help

Comment: Looks like this has been asked and answered. Here you go:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934642/having-a-problem-removing-textviews-from-a-linearlayout-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: I have tried the invalidate method that that thread suggested but it still wont work :(

Answer (score 4):

You need to set an `onClickListener` for your checkbox, and set the visibility of the TextView to GONE in it. Also, you don't have to remove and add the TextView. Try this:

```
breakCheck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    if(breakCheck.isChecked()){
        prompt_break.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else{
        prompt_break.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To make a view disappear, set its visibility to GONE (if you want to resize the layout) or INVISIBLE (if you want to keep the space where it was empty) using setVisibility().  Its generally better to hide it like this than actually delete it, its cheaper processor-wise if you're going to recreate it again later.  Just set an onClickListener for the checkbox and change the text view's visibility based on the value of the checkbox when onClickListener is called.

Comment: should this work on the emulator?

Comment: It should.  Usually its input and sensor related things that fail on emulators.  Unless you're writing automated tests I'm not sure if I'd bother with emulators though-  devices tend to be a more real world test and are far better performance-wise.