# Removing from ArrayList not working properly

Tags: android

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        final TextView todo = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 180);
        todo.setLayoutParams(params);

        todo.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this, todo, layout) {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                todo.animate().translationX(500).alpha(0f).setDuration(250).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        layout.removeView(todo);
                        Log.i("REMOVE111111111111111", Boolean.toString(textList.remove(todo.getText().toString())));
                        Log.i("REMOVE22222222222222", Boolean.toString(todoList.remove(todo)));
                    }
                })
                .start();

            }
        });
        todoList.add(todo);
        Collections.sort(todoList, new todoComparator());
        textList.clear();
        for (TextView t: todoList) {
            textList.add(t.getText().toString());
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (TextView t: todoList) {
            if (counter > 0) {
                ((ViewGroup) todo.getParent()).removeView(todo);
            }
            layout.addView(todo);
            counter++;
        }
```

When I swipe a textview to the right, I expect it to be removed along with the corresponding data in the textList and todoList. I tried to test this and found that in the onAnimationEnd method my textList.remove() and todoList.remove() seems to return false some times and I'm not really sure why. Any ideas? Thank you.
Sorry, for not being clear. The textviews are being removed, but textList.remove() and todoList.remove() return false at times.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5935515/4385913) it might help you

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The textviews are being removed, but textList.remove() and todoList.remove() return false at times.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your touchlistener on "layout", not "todo"

Comment: Can you explain why I would do this? The textviews are being removed but the textList.remove() and todoList.remove() return false some times.